# Android app crashes when EditText is empty

Tags: android, android-edittext

This is a simple tip calculator that crashes whenever one of my EditText boxes is empty and the button is pressed.  My impression is that there should be a try/catch or if statement to handle the exception, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I'm pulling my hair out over what I assume is a quick fix so any help would be really appreciated.

```
package com.gamejig.tip_calculator.tip_calculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        double tipAmount;
        double finalBill;
        double billBeforeTip;
        double tipPercentage;

        TextView txt_Tip_Amount1;
        TextView txt_Final_Bill;
        EditText txt_BillBeforeTip;
        EditText txt_Tip_Percentage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txt_Tip_Amount1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Tip_Amount);
        txt_Final_Bill = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_Final_Bill);
        txt_BillBeforeTip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Bill_Amount);
        txt_Tip_Percentage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_Tip_Percentage);

        setupMessageButton();
    }

    public void setupMessageButton() {
        Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(txt_BillBeforeTip.getText().toString());
                tipPercentage = Double.parseDouble(txt_Tip_Percentage.getText().toString());

                tipAmount = billBeforeTip * tipPercentage;
                finalBill = tipAmount + billBeforeTip;
                txt_Tip_Amount1.setText(String.format("%.02f", tipAmount));
                txt_Final_Bill.setText(String.format("%.02f", finalBill));

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post your logcat if possible

Comment: Double.parseDouble(txt_BillBeforeTip.getText().toString());

This can not convert null or empty value to double so, better to check,

    if(txt_BillBeforeTip.getText().toString().compareTo("")==0) {
      // Put your alert to enter value here
    } else {
      // Your code 
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(txt_BillBeforeTip.getText().toString());
 tipPercentage = Double.parseDouble(txt_Tip_Percentage.getText().toString());
```

Change to

```
 try {
     billBeforeTip = Double.parseDouble(txt_BillBeforeTip.getText().toString());
     tipPercentage = Double.parseDouble(txt_Tip_Percentage.getText().toString());
 } catch ( Exception e) {
     Log.e("InvalidNumber","Can not parse zero string"); 
     return; // Or another exception handling.
 }
```

You got a parse error. Because you cant convert `""` to `Double`.

Comment: Explanation and reduced amount of unnecessary unchanged code would be nice.

Comment: This worked.  I had the variables in two places, including inside the try block, when I was attempting it myself.  I thought they needed to be gathered from the EditText outside try block first.  Thanks for the help.